# LWC iterating over a loop from apex is not let me change the data

Tags: lightning-web-components, read-only, lwc-dev-server

today I was trying to iterate and compare an array given from Apex to create a new one without repeated values, but I just couldn't. It was like my logic code was ignored.

Then I was reading in stackexchange that when you retrieve data from Apex you need to make a copy of the data before change it because otherwise you won't be able to change anything due to a 'read-only' or frozen data.

I tried with spread operator, map, slice, Object.assignment,JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy) (almost everything I know) but I didn't find a solution.
Finally I filtered the values from Apex and It worked for me, but I still have the doubt of how can I proceed in this cases with LWC.

Here is my code, so If anyone know a solution or have faced the same issue, I'll be very gratefull!

Apex code:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = false)
public static List<String> getPicklistValuesByProduct(string quoteId){
    List<QuoteLineItem> qli = [
        SELECT Product2.Family
        FROM QuoteLineItem
        WHERE QuoteId =:quoteId
    ];
    return qli;
}
```

LWC code:

```
myData = [];
myFormattedData = []
connectedCallback() {
    this.getSelectableValues();
}

getSelectableValues() {
    apexcall({quoteId: this.recordId}).then(data => {
        this.myData = data.map(element => ({...element}));
        this.setPicklistValues();
    }).catch(//error catch)
}

setPicklistValues() {
    this.myData.forEach(e =>{
        if (this.myFormattedData.length == 0) {
            this.myFormattedData.push(e)
        }
        if (myFormattedData.length > 0 && !this.myFormattedData.includes(e)) { 
            this.myFormattedData.push(e)
        }  
    })
}
```

Result = myFormattedData is not filtered, is just equal to the data given by the Server

Comment: `parse(stringify())` has worked for me.

Comment: @Julian Gutierrez Caligaris what does each of your "e" items look like in your this.myData array? a "string" or an object {id: something ...}?

Comment: Yeah finally worked the parse(stringify) the problem was that I was filling the array with ({label:e,value:e}) to an checkbox, and for some reason that doesn't work fine. But when i filled the array with just the single row and then i formatted the data for the checkbox, It worked fine :). Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has a `Set` class, which is like an `Array`, but must contain unique values. Converting an array to a set and back to an array will remove duplicate values.

```
this.myData = new Array(new Set(this.myData));
```

Comment: You can also: `[...new Set(this.myData)]`